# How to set dirty icon in property grid in extjs

Tags: extjs

I need to add dirty icon (a small red color icon) whenever a row is edited.
But I'm getting some JS error like,

> "return Ext.fly(row).down(column.getCellSelector())"
>    cannot read property down

```
cell = Ext.fly(e.row).down(e.column.getCellSelector()).addCls('x-grid-dirty-cell')
```

Comment: share a fiddle reproducing the issue so that someone can help you.

Comment: The error means that `Ext.fly(e.row)` returns `null` probably because of invalid `e.row` value which doesn't point to correct `element`. Check the value of `e` object.